# can I write a DialUp listener program for ubuntu with java?

Tags: java, dial-up

I want to develop a program for ubuntu platform, That listens to DialUp modem and get Calls and send them to my php program that's running on my localhost.

for example when somebody calls my phone line, my listener program give the number and run this query:

> http://127.0.0.1:80/listen.php?caller=ThePhoneNumber

How can I do that? is there any classes in java for that?

Comment: Java is a general purpose programming language. You can program anything in it. Your question is too vague.

Comment: @Raedwald http://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/products/gallery_large/USB56KEM3.Main.jpg

Comment: @Raedwald that's a dial up modem, I want make a program with java that listens to dial up modem and save the incomming calls

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need native tools for that. You can make `pppd` answer the call and run a custom script or program. But I have not fiddled with that for a long time. See [linux modem howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Modem-HOWTO/). There should be plenty of information.